# ArcGIS Map and NextJS rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rendering, arcgis-js-api

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while and I haven't found any suitable solution on the net.
I am trying to solve a rendering issue using nextJS and Arcgis JS API. In [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/SebMartinus/testNextJS/draft/nice-sky?file=%2Fpages%2F_app.js), I have created a simple app where I am incrementing a counter every 5 seconds and display a map.The counter is an useState hook and it seems that every time it is updated, the map is re render again. How can I render the map a single time.
I have been following [this recommendation](https://thomasryan.dev/2022/01/next-js-and-arcgis-js-web-app.html) and the get started page on the NextJS website.I had a read at some questions on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68670753/why-is-nextjs-persistent-layout-re-rendering-all-the-time)  as well...
My code to add the map is the following...

```
    const EsriMap = ()=>{

const mapDiv = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("load map")
    // Grab the webmap object out of the UseRef() hook
    // so that we can mutate it.
    const map=new ArcGISMap({
      basemap: "osm",
    })
    // let map = webmap.current;
            const view = new MapView({
              map,
              container: mapDiv.current,
              center: [140, -27],
              scale: 40000000,
            });
    // Configure the map...

}, []);

return <div className={styles.mapDiv} ref={mapDiv}></div>
```

}
export default EsriMap;

I would appreciate if someone can help me to solve this one.

Comment: your codesandbox link doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

I noticed that you are using the counter directly in App.js
This will cause the application to rerender each time the state of the counter changes

**Solution:**

You may consider moving your counter into a separate component or custom hook to avoid the rerender of all app

Ps: if you did not figure out how to do that I could prepare an example for you

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thank You for your response and your time Malek. I think I does a similar re-rendering if I move the component to a child component of the App.js. I will have a closer look at it